# Integral involving gaussian and triangle function

Tags: integration

I would like to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \quad tri(x)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a}\right)dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of the triangle function? (i.e. what is its extent?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$\text{tri}(x) = \begin{cases}1-\left| \frac{x}{2} \right | & |x| \le 2\\0 & |x| \gt 2 \end{cases}$$

Then, after making the substitution $u=x-x_0$ and doing some algebra, you can show that the stated integral is equal to

$$\left ( 1+\frac{x_0}{2}\right) \int_{-2-x_0}^{-x_0} du \, e^{-u^2/a} + \left ( 1-\frac{x_0}{2}\right) \int_{-2-x_0}^{-x_0} du \, e^{-u^2/a} + \\ \frac12 \int_{-2-x_0}^{-x_0} du \, u\,e^{-u^2/a} - \frac12 \int_{-x_0}^{2-x_0} du \, u\,e^{-u^2/a}$$

which in turn is equal to

$$\left ( 1+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)  \frac{\sqrt{\pi a}}{2} \left [\text{erf}\left(-\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{a}}\right) - \text{erf}\left(\frac{-2-x_0}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \right ] + \left ( 1-\frac{x_0}{2}\right)  \frac{\sqrt{\pi a}}{2} \left [\text{erf}\left(\frac{2-x_0}{\sqrt{a}}\right) - \text{erf}\left(-\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \right ]\\-\frac{a}{4} \left [e^{-(2+x_0)^2/a} + e^{-(2-x_0)^2/a}-2 e^{-x_0^2/a} \right ] $$

Comment: Why do you define the triangle function in that way? I mean, the result is dependent on the scaling of the triangle function, right?

Comment: @JFNJr: Because it is the FT of $\text{sinc}^2(x)$.

Comment: According to wikipedia, yours is $tri(x/2)$ definition.

Comment: @JFNJr: If you wanted the Wikipedia definition, then you should have stated that in your problem statement.  I used the definition I gave above because the integral is so provocatively a convolution.  In fact, someone even asked you about the definition and you did not provide an answer.  We may be all smart in math and all, but most of us do not read minds.

Comment: I do apologize. I have seen the quest about the definition after your answer. Thank you so much for your help in the last questions that I posted.

Comment: @JFNJr: You're welcome.  Just please next time be more specific in your problem statements; that way, you will get much more out of this.